# How am I using apollo combineResolvers() wrong?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm following a [Udemy course on apollo](https://www.udemy.com/course/graphql-apollo-server-api-nodejs-mongodb/), and also fairly new to nodeJS. This course has gone well so far, but on a step where they are introducing combineResolvers() from the graphql-resolvers module, something is breaking.

It is trying to add an authentication step to a resolver by using combineResolvers() from graphql-resolvers module. Each part works fine independently, meaning the isAuthenticated() is working fine by itself, as well as the user query that gets a user by user.id.

When I use combineResolvers(), I get an INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id.". Also, when I get this error, the console.log from the isAuthenticated() is displayed with an email, so it should return/skip, but the console.log from the user resolver, before the users.find... , is not. How is it failing between them?

Here is the relevant code. The commented lines are the ones that worked before introducing combineResolvers:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { combineResolvers } = require('graphql-resolvers');

const { users, tasks } = require('../constants');
const User = require('../database/models/user');
const { isAuthenticated } = require('./middleware');

module.exports = {
    Query: {
        users: () => {
            return users;
        }, 
        // user: ( _, args, { email }) => {
        //     console.log("===", email);
        //     return users.find(user => user.id == args.id);
        // }
        user: combineResolvers(isAuthenticated, ( _, { id }, { email }) => {
            console.log("===", email);
            return users.find(user => user.id == id);
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the isAuthenticated module, from /resolvers/middleware/index.js:

```
const skip = require('graphql-resolvers');

module.exports.isAuthenticated = (_, __, { email }) => {
    console.log("isAuthenticated...email : ", email);
    if (!email) {
        throw new Error("Access Denied! Please login to continue");
    }
    return skip;
}
```

Comment: From the docs https://github.com/lucasconstantino/graphql-resolvers/blob/master/docs/API.md#combineresolvers
> Combines resolver functions into one resolver in a first-result-returns manner: all resolvers will be called sequentially with the same initial arguments until one resolves to something other than undefined; when that happens, the resolved value will be returned and the remaining resolver functions will be ignored.

You return `skip` in `isAuthenticated` which (presumably) doesn't have any `id` on it, and your schema demands it.

return `undefined` from `isAuthenticated` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define combined resolver before export (as in docs, no real change, both methods should work) ...

... but probably you need to use `async/await` for DB/datasource related resolvers:

```
const authedUserById = combineResolvers(
  isAuthenticated, 
  async ( _, { id }, { email }) => {
        console.log("==>>", id, email);
        return await users.find(user => user.id == id);
  }
)

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    users: () => {
        return users;
    }, 
    user: authedUserById
  }
}
```

What `id` is logged??? how tested? how passed variable?

Comment: Why re-define combineResolvers? It's destructured from the graphql-resolvers package.

Comment: no redefinition here, only 'instantiate' combined resolver before assigning it to (prop) type

Comment: updated, what 'id' value is logged ?? why not use 'more modern' `export const`, `import` ... compiler config/issues?

Comment: I tried this; same thing happened as with the original code, it doesn't log the "==>>", so it's not even getting to that method; the  "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id." seems to indicate that the isAuthenticated method is returning an empty User, instead of moving on to the next resolver

Comment: it shouldn't, only throw or undefined ... node version???  ...  insert more loggers inside isAuthed .... copy combineResolvers function source from from https://github.com/lucasconstantino/graphql-resolvers/blob/master/src/combineResolvers.js (instead of import/require) and check if it works, then change code to insert some logging

Comment: @user26270 I'm facing exactly the same issue , how did you end you solving it ?

Comment: @PeterMalik I don't think I ever did; I moved on to other tutorials; currently going through a book HandsOnTypescript with React and GraphQL for building a full stack app

Comment: @user26270 Got it ! I've been trying to debug this particular issue right now for hours , but then I realized I could make my own `combineResolvers` by basically awaiting the `isAuthenticated` resolver , and then solving the other one . Good luck !